# Is there a way to compare NTFS and FAT32 last modified QDateTime's while accounting for the system configured time zone & DST?

Tags: qt, datetime, ntfs, fat32, qdatetime

Hi I need to be able to compare the last modified QDateTime's of two files that were copies of each other to tell if they have been modified and are no longer equal. One file is stored on an NTFS filesystem and the other is on FAT32. The file being modified is the NTFS one.

I am aware of the FAT32 2 second precision of the modified timestamp but the problem is after correcting for that I still need to be able to account for the effects of the system time zone DST settings. As it is now, during standard time, if a copy of the NTFS file was made to the FAT32 filesystem before standard time during daylight savings time, the two files as compared using QDateTime's have a difference of 1 hour after a restart (before restart the difference is 0). Is there any way to have Qt intelligently be aware of DST and recognize the time difference? Do I have to resort to the Win API or STL? Thanks.

Both Qt::UTC and Qt::LocalTime timespecs have the same results.

```
QDateTime sourceDateTime(sourceFileInfo.lastModified());
QDateTime targetDateTime(targetFileInfo.lastModified());

qint64 sourceMSecs(sourceDateTime.toMSecsSinceEpoch());
qint64 targetMSecs(targetDateTime.toMSecsSinceEpoch());

qint64 sourceMSecsAdjustedtoFAT32((sourceMSecs + 1999) / 2000 * 2000);

if ( sourceMSecsAdjustedtoFAT32 > targetMSecs ) .......
```

Comment: Are you saying that the one hour offset is *always* present? Is it possible that the computer has been running continuously since *before* the DST has been applied? If you can, are you able to restart that computer and see if the offset is still present?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that aspect of the situation. After DST takes effect, before the next restart, the datetime difference is 0. After the next restart it is one hour off. I'll edit the original post tomorrow.

Comment: Be aware that NTFS uses UTC for timestamps, while FAT always uses the local time. I don't use Windows normally, so I can't really test this right away, but I've done some research, and there are known problems related to DST and NTFS/FAT timestamp results. I'll wait for your reply, but, in the meantime, I suggest you to check [this related MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times). Also note that since Qt 6.6 QFileInfo provides function overloads for `QDateTime` that do *not* convert the original time to the local one (which is the default behavior).

Comment: Unfortunately already read that article :) I'm lost enough to post here.

Comment: After reading again your question and comment, I believe that the problem may be consistent with that MSDN article, it's just the other way around: when the file is copied, it uses the *current* time settings, even if the file has a time that has a different time setting; in reality, you should take into account the current time settings (if it has changed since system start) and correct it by one hour: it will result in a currently wrong offset of one hour, but that's because how it works, but after the restart it should have the correct time.